# Compress windows pdb symbol files stops the debugger from loading them

Tags: debugging, windbg

I wrote a script to host a symbol server. I do not wish to use symstore.exe.
What I do is :- Get the GUID of the PDB and the age. concatenate both and put my pdb file inside a folder named by the resulting string.

My symbol server/share works fine.

Now,
To implement compression, I use the compress tool from Microsoft, but the symbols stop being loaded by windbg.
Can anyone help me out with it? From what I understand, compressing the pdb and renaming it to *.pd_ should work fine.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're not using dbghelp 6.1 or earlier but what you stated should work: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681416(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: To read the PDB, I'm using the DIA SDK. I return my GUID and age on pipe to my python script.
the symbol server without using compress works fine but after I compress everything, it doesn't.

Comment: There is a comment on that page `When cascading, files are not uncompressed unless the target store is the leftmost store in the path. If there is only one store in the path and it contains a compressed file, SymSrv will copy the file to the default downstream store and open it from there, even though the default downstream store is not indicated in they symbol path.` so is your store the leftmost path?

Comment: My https://*store is the leftmost store in my symbol path list. But, this states on the link u provided  that -""" or the left of the store list, it would not be possible to copy any found files to it and the chain would be broken. Furthermore, because the symbol handler cannot open a file from a web site, an HTTP-based store should not be the leftmost or only store on the list"
So, I should try to use the symbol server with my https path in the right?

Comment: It is a little confusing but it seems to indicate that it allows a hierachy, they call it cascading, but my interpretation is that this follows the usual lookup rules in that it's read from the left onwards

Comment: You were right. For compressed files, there must be a local symbol store provided where it copies and expands the compressed symbol. Put this as an answer and I will mark it :D

I used a format like srv*C:\localSymbols*<mysymbolserver>; 
and it worked

Comment: Does your script run on Linux?

Comment: @ThomasW., no. I'm using DIA SDK to build an executable to read the GUID and AGE of the PDB, which I pipe to my python script. My python is for checking file existence, creating the directory structure and copying the files. So it won't work on linux. I've go no idea about how linux symbols are indexed.

Comment: @lel: Thanks for the answer. I want Windows symbols be served by Linux :-)

Comment: @ThomasW.; then this can work. You will need to use a windows system to read the PDB though and generate the hashes. Once it is done, you can create your index on a linux machine, then make a HTTP/s server and enable directory listing on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681416%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

compressed symbols files are supported so long as you use the compress.exe tool that is distributed with the resource kit.

The compressed files can be located on a network resource and are copied and decompressed when loaded, this means that you must specify a local symbol store where it will be copied to and decompressed and this must be the first entry because if you specify paths in a different order then it may not be able to copy and decompress it so as you've found it works if you specify the local path first.

In your case the following worked: `srv*C:\localSymbols*<mysymbolserver>;`